# mysql limit result to first phrase per row

Tags: mysql, sql, phrase, sql-limit

I'm trying to limit the result of a column value to only the first line/phrase.
I know there is an option like SUBSTRING(), but this is counting the characters, which does not do the wanted job.
Is there a way to cut the data on the first line-break and only show that first sentence?

Comment: Kindly provide the query you tried. This is how nobody understands what you need and what is you error.

Comment: Hi Gaurang, ...Tim did understand what I want to get as a result, so it seems to be clear enough

Answer (score 1):

Use `SUBSTRING_INDEX`:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('First sentence.  Second sentence', '.', 1) AS output
FROM dual;

    output
1   First sentence
```

### Demo

Comment: This is already getting really close, but if i'm not mistaking this will check when it is reaching the first "." in the info... The info in that column could have a "." in the first part of the sentence, but I don't want it to break at that time. isn't there something like "at line break, or at new line" that can be used?

Comment: Does your data even have newlines?  Just because you see your text wrap does not mean there is actually a line break there.

Comment: yes it does... users seem to insert all sorts of content, but I need to keep the possible allowed amount of entered text high.. it's used for something else also, but it just appears in an ugly way in the jqgrid overview.. so that's the place I want to limit it.

Comment: You never answered my question.  Do line break characters appear in the text, and if so, do you want the first line, or do you want the first sentence?

Comment: the line breaks are made by just pressing enter, there are no visual characters inside the test...I tried to put an example, but the formatting does not seem to work in comments in here :(

Comment: Then use `SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, '\n', 1)`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solutions that works like a charm for my problem, hope it will help someone else also ;)
This is how I adapted the query:

```
 CONCAT(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(COLUMN,'\n',' '),1,75),'...') AS COLUMNNAME
```

Which results in getting the info from that column, removing new lines, sticking it all together with a space in between and then returning only the 75 first characters, followed by "..."